# Resize graph plotted in d3.js graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am developing a dashboard using flask and I am using d3.js at the client side. I  have plotted a graph on html which I do want to resize it to a perfect size so that I can create a sidebar. How can I resize this graph. Here is a section of DIV class that I am plotting on html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="chart" id="bargraph">
                <script>
                    var graphs = {{plot | safe}};
                    Plotly.plot('bargraph',graphs,{},width = 200);

                </script>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Help me understand how I can resize that graph being plotted by d3.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that your chart will be fit all the space inside `id="bargraph` you need to get the width of it, and then put in Plotly constructor. 
It could be something like this:

```js
 <script>
   var graphs = {{plot | safe}};
   // taking container width where we want to put chart
   var getContainerWidth = document.querySelector('#bargraph').offsetWidth

   // add width to our chart constructor
   Plotly.plot('bargraph',graphs,{},width = getContainerWidth);
  </script>
```